# How to translate 新科状元?

Tags: translation

I don't know if other countries had similar systems for electing officials, but I often struggle to find the right English equivalent for 新科状元 or just 状元 when trying to translate Chinese text.

Are there any good suggestions or ideas?

Comment: from wiki: Zhuàngyuán, or trạng nguyên in Vietnamese, variously translated into English as principal graduate, primus, or optimus,[1] was the title given to the scholar who achieved the highest score on highest level of the Imperial examination,省試 [ja](in Tang) and 殿試 [zh](in Song)[2] in ancient China and Vietnam.

Answer (score 4):

Like all cross-linguistic and cross-cultural translations, this requires a knowledge of the context, not just of the source material but also of the target language.

In medieval and Renaissance Western Europe, the 科举 was not "a thing" [in the same way](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jzr3DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA23) as in Imperial China (and East Asia), with the *viva voce* being more traditional. However, with greater knowledge of these practices, an accepted translation for certain terms formed, e.g. 科举 = *imperial examination*.

There are plenty of possible translations for 状元 which are native to English, that any good Chinese dictionary should give:

- top scorer
- best in class
- top of the class
- leading light (best applied to the world of work)

However, in most academic texts, [zhuangyuan](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=zhuangyuan&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czhuangyuan%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Czhuangyuan%3B%2Cc0) is used, in recognition of its origin.

Answer (score 1):

If in urgent situation with no time to explain the background, New (National) Exam Champ(ion) might be a good choice.  In modern world, 状元 refers to top No. 1 in all kinds wide range exam, thus 市状元 municipal level, 省状元 provincial/state level; you can also add type of exam (competition) like 高考状元，奥数状元，even 电竞状元。

Answer (score 0):

There are several other phrases related to 狀元.

No. 1 狀元, 新科狀元 usually refer the person who is the new number one in some kind of exam. (In ancient China, it was a national-wide exam.)

No. 2 榜眼

No. 3 探花

名落孫山, which is a 成語, means "failed to pass the examination".

e.g. 這次大學入學考試我鄰居的兒子**名落孫山**，只好來年再努力看看了！